# Unicode characters in NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode

Here is my code and the logs, it will be more efficient than a long speech :)

```
NSString* cat = [categories objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"category : :%@:", cat);
NSString* decodedString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[cat cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];
NSLog(@"category decoede : %@", decodedString);
```

LOG : category : :Boissons fra?ches:

And after, I get this exception : `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'`

I just want to convert strings like "Boissons fra?ches" in "Boissons fraîches". How can I do ?

**EDIT**

I just want to get content of a CSV file. My complete code is :

```
// Getting content of CSV file
NSError* error;
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"categories" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString* data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
NSArray* categories = [data componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

for (int i = 0; i < categories.count; ++i) {
    NSString* cat = [categories objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"categorie : :%@:", [categories objectAtIndex:i]);
    NSString* decodedString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[cat cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]];
    NSLog(@"categorie : %@", decodedString);
    [self.categories addObject:decodedString];
}
```

Comment: Look here: http://macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxvi-parsing-csv-data

Comment: What encoding is the actual CSV file? Try `NSUTF8StringEncoding` if you don't know. Or try running the `file` command on the file from the command line. That should show you the file's encoding.

Comment: You have loaded the file using `NSASCIIStringEncoding`. If the file is truly ASCII, then it can't properly represent "Boissons fraîches" and the data was lost. However, I suspect the file is not ASCII. You must find out what encoding was used to create the file. If it comes from a program, hopefully that program documents the encoding it used.

Comment: @rmaddy : I try your command and this is what I get : `categories.csv: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CR line terminators`.

I already tried `NSUTF8StringEncoding` and the NSString called `data` is null :/

Comment: How was the CSV file created? As Ken stated in his comment, look into the tool used to create the file. If you have the option, recreate the CSV file again but specify that you want UTF-8 encoding. This is always best. Otherwise, try all of the different encodings. Start with `NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding` is you used MS Windows or `NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding` is you used a Mac.

Comment: First use characterAtIndex to extract the problem character and print its decimal value.  Then look up that character in the likely character set maps to see what character set was used.  Then, ideally, work backwards to the creation of the NSString to use the correct encoding, otherwise translate the character individually to what you need.

Comment: As @KenThomases notes, you should not have used NSASCIIStringEncoding. The important thing to note is that when Cocoa says "ASCII" it really means ASCII, not "extended ASCII" or some other "ASCII-like" encoding. The character î cannot be encoded in ASCII.

Comment: @rmaddy : I created a file with Microsoft Excel, it was a XLSX file before the conversion.

Comment: @Seb Hopefully Excel gives you the option to export the spreadsheet using UTF-8 encoding. This would be the best option.

Comment: @rmaddy How can you do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C string conversion is failing because you have a character in the original string that cannot be represented in the default C string encoding (which is MacRoman, an older 8-bit encoding similar to ISO Latin-1.)

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but `[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]` is almost never the encoding you want to use. If you can elaborate, I might be able to provide another approach to the problem.

Comment: I edited my question in order to precise my aim. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just want to convert my string with strange characters to a normal and readable string.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `NSASCIIStringEncoding` in `[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error]`, you need to find out the encoding of the text file and use the appropriate enum value.